# Were there (or are there) any Dark Wizards who were Sorted into the Hufflepuff House?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat, dark-arts

I just finished watching *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's (Philosopher's) Stone* on DVD. Not my first time seeing in the movie by a long shot, but Quirrell captured my attention during the film. He was a servant of Lord Voldemort I have heard on Pottermore that Quinius Quirrell was a Ravenclaw, and that Hufflepuff has had the **fewest** Dark wizards, so I started thinking of some famous Dark Witches and Wizards each of the four Houses may have.

Slytherin had Lord Voldemort (most famously, along with many Death Eaters)
Gryffindor had Wormtail; Ravenclaw had Quirrell.

I have tried to find some Dark Witches or Wizards from Hufflepuff, but only in vain.

Are there any current Dark Wizards (most likely in Azkaban) or former Dark Wizards who are known to have been a part of Hufflepuff House?

Comment: Quirrel wasn't so much a servant of Voldemort as he was possessed - there's nothing I remember in the books or movie that suggest it was voluntary on his part. It just happened that Quirrel was in the wrong place at the wrong time when Voldemort was looking for a host.

Comment: @HorusKol That's wrong, Quirrel was only possessed after he failed to get the stone from Gringott's, as evidenced by his discussion with Harry stating that he[Voldemort] "...decided he[V] would have to keep a closer watch on me[Quirrel]".

Comment: hmm - fair enough, but still not entirely convinced Quirrel was acting of his own volition

Comment: He doesn't have to be possessed to believe that aiding Lord V was the only way to save his scrawny ars

Comment: @cbbcbail he may not have known about Peter Pettigrew, but he would be overlooking the fact that Sirius Black was in prison (wrongly i might add) for supposedly being a dark wizard. therefore that statement must be taken with a pinch of salt xx

Answer (score 15):

The Hufflepuff welcome letter on Pottermore makes a claim about their Dark wizard turnout:

> However, it’s true that Hufflepuff is a bit lacking in one area. **We’ve produced the fewest Dark wizards of any house in this school.** Of course, you’d expect Slytherin to churn out evil-doers, seeing as they’ve never heard of fair play and prefer cheating over hard work any day, but even Gryffindor (the house we get on best with) has produced a few dodgy characters.

Of course, take that with a pinch of salt, since it comes from a Hufflepuff prefect.

That it says “the fewest” might suggest that they have turned out a non-zero number of Dark wizards/witches in their history, but less than the other houses (so the answer to the original question would be yes). But I don’t know of any canon examples that back up that interpretation.

It’s also possible that this Prefect doesn’t know of any instances of Dark wizards in Hufflepuff, but doesn’t want to say “no Dark wizards” in case there are some that they don’t know about.

Comments in the Slytherin welcome letter also hint at Dark wizards across all three houses, but again fails to cite specific instances:

> I’m not denying that we’ve produced our share of Dark wizards, but **so have the other three houses – they just don’t like admitting it**.

But again, that comes with the bias of being written by a Slytherin prefect.

Overall, I’d say it’s pretty likely that Hufflepuff have turned out some Dark wizards and witches, but they probably pale in comparison to the number and notoriety of those turned out by Slytherin, hence they don’t tend to get mentioned much.

Comment: *"It’s also possible that this Prefect doesn’t know of any instances of dark wizards in Hufflepuff, but doesn’t want to say 'no Dark wizards' in case there are some that they don’t know about."*  This is the most reasonable interpretation; +1.

Comment: And it would be very Slytherin to assume that every House has a few black sheep even without evidence of any from Hufflepuff.

Answer (score 10):

[Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hufflepuff) suggests that Hufflepuff has the fewest dark wizards of any house, but I have found several accounts that suggest that they have none.

So either they have none, or they have a few very-unknown ones as at least one [Slytherin](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Slytherin_House#Welcome_Message_2) claims.

Comment: Just a note: your second link is misleading in its representation of Slytherins. We are *not* chosen for being bigoted purebloods. We are chosen for being the seeds of greatness who seek fame and success, and we possess much cunning and no small amount of wisdom. But you're probably right about Hufflepuff; they are of the greatest integrity out of all the houses, and JKR's daughter was at least partially correct when she said we should all want to be Hufflepuffs.

Comment: I added an edit make it the voice of one person, as against to all Slitherin. However, it was a cited source from the wiki so vOv

Answer (score 5):

In an alternate timeline, Cedric Diggory, a prominent Hufflepuff alumnus, suffers a deep humiliation during the Triwizard Tournament and ultimately becomes a dark wizard and a Death Eater.

> **SCORPIUS:** *He wasn’t supposed to do it alone. Cedric was supposed to win it with him. But **we humiliated him out of the tournament. And
> as a result of that humiliation he became a Death Eater.** I can’t work
> out what he did in the Battle of Hogwarts — whether he killed someone
> or — but he did something and it changed everything.*
>
> **SNAPE:** *Cedric Diggory killed only one wizard and not a significant one — Neville Longbottom.*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *Oh, of course, that’s it! Professor Longbottom was supposed to kill Nagini, Voldemort’s snake. Nagini had to die before
> Voldemort could die. That’s it! You’ve solved it! We destroyed Cedric,
> he killed Neville, Voldemort won the battle. Can you see? Can you see
> it?*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Cursed Child - ACT THREE, SCENE FIVE</sup></sub>

Comment: While I dislike the source, this is the only plausible answer here which isn't just restating the question. +1

Comment: Am I the only Harry Potter fan who really enjoyed HP and the Cursed Child?

Comment: @Wallnut - I'm pretty sure you are. Also Rowling's accountant likes it just fine, but for different reasons

Comment: Only if you know that in HP and the Cursed child, there are just so many timelines as the kids had the time itself. So that doesn't make a single reality, even so the Hufflepuff had fewest

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, Hufflepuff dark wizards likely exist.

In an interview, JKR confirms that there are people connected with Death Eaters in the houses other than Slytherin, and does not in any way attempt to specifically exclude Hufflepuff.

> ES: But there a lot of Death Eater children in the other houses, are there?
>
> JKR: You will have people connected with Death Eaters in the other houses, yeah, absolutely. 
> <sub><sup>*[- The Leaky Cauldron interview (July 16, 2005)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm)*</sup></sub>

She doesn’t state explicitly that there are actual Death Eaters in Hufflepuff, and it’s possible that there are only people connected with them but no one who actually joined them there, but it seems likely from this that there would be at least one Death Eaters in Hufflepuff. The houses of many of the wizards that could be classified as dark, even the named ones, are not mentioned. For example, the houses of Barty Crouch Jr, Rookwood, Yaxley, and Rowle are never stated or implied. Any of them could be a Hufflepuff, particularly if they did not have strong traits of any of the other houses, as Helga Hufflepuff took all students.

> *“Good Hufflepuff, she took the rest,
>
> And taught them all she knew,
>
> Thus the houses and their founders
>
> Retained friendships firm and true.”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 11 (The Sorting Hat’s New Song)*</sup></sub>

Considering that Hogwarts has existed for centuries, and during that time there are likely to have been several Dark wizards who attended Hogwarts since its founding, it seems almost impossible that no Dark wizards were ever in Hufflepuff. This is particularly clear when it is kept in mind that students who did not fit into one of the other houses may become Hufflepuff because of the Founders’ individual preferences and Helga being the one willing to accept all students.

Answer (score -2):

But there's this quote from the first book:

> "Better Hufflepuff than Slytherin," said Hagrid darkly. "There's not a single witch or wizard who went bad who wasn't in Slytherin. You-Know-Who was one."

In the film, pretty much the same quote is made by Ron. This implies that *all* the dark wizards were from Slytherin.

Comment: Peter Pettigrew was a Gryffindor.

Comment: @MarkBeadles well, precisely, and as OP notes Quirrell was a Ravenclaw. My point is just that the books give contradictory information on this point.

Comment: Don't mistake a character's statement for the author's. Hagrid said that, not JK Rowling. He might have been mistaken, or simplifying, or exaggerating.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I agree; Hagrid was kicked out of Hogwarts _because_ of a Slytherin.  He's biased.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Also, Hagrid didn't know about Peter Pettigrew being bad when he said this.

Comment: And he certainly didn't have a clue about Quirrel, who he then had several rounds with later int he book - and his trust of non-Slytherines nearly resulted in the Dark Lord's return.  Think about that one.

Comment: Hufflepuff dark wizards; kind of like Bavarian Nazis. Conscripted but not committed would be my guess.

Answer (score -8):

Umbridge is widely believed to be a Hufflepuff, although in Pottermore it says she was a Slytherin, evidence suggests otherwise. The traights of a Hufflepuff are: Hard-working - she is definitely trying hard to ... give extreme power to the witches and wizards and destroy all muggles, loyalty - umbridge's blind loyalty towards the minestry makes people believe she is hufflepuff, friendship - still working on this one, and honesty - Umbridge is honest but not in a nice way: when she said she was going to punish Harry 'the way she think he diserves' she was brutally honest and used his own blood as ink and made him write lines.

Also, Helga Hufflepuff (the founder of Hufflepuff) looks a lot like umbridge. This might just be my imagination but look at the image attached. So she could be a distant relative of Helga's, which most definitely would put her in Hufflepuff.

[image: Heres the pic]

Comment: According to the [Dolores Umbridge fact file on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/dolores-umbridge), she is a Slytherin, and that section of the page is stated to be **by J.K. Rowling**. I think other evidences or beliefs cannot overrule what the author explicitly and publicly said.

Comment: Your "evidence" is not evidence, but you adapting facts to suit your theory.