# Did any Gryffindor marry a Slytherin?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat, marriage

Supposedly House Gryffindor and House Slytherin have a centuries-old enmity, but at some point this must have been overcome at least by a few individuals.

**In canon (books, Pottermore, interviews, anything with JKR's stamp of approval)**, has there ever been a Gryffindor-Slytherin marriage?

<sup><sub>I'm sure one could write a good Romeo and Juliet-style story along these lines, but fanfics are NOT accepted!</sub></sup>

Comment: Nice question! :D I'll do some sleuthing if no one finds anything

Comment: Possible, based on skimming the Harry Potter Wikia [page about marriage](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) (yeah, I know ... thus this is a comment!): Septimus Weasley and Cedrella Black. There may be other possibilities listed there, but I must get to other things.

Comment: Andromeda - Ted Tonks ?  But iam not sure Ted Tonks was in gryffindor.Andromeda must have been in slytherin because 'except sirius , almost all blacks were in slytherin'

Comment: @CandiedMango [No he wasn't](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Tonks) :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Tehe ;) https://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/blackfamilytree.html I probably took the shorthand by Andromeda too hastily.

Comment: @Randal'Thor where on that page does it say what house he was in? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @JAB I'm not sure if it's canonically known which house he was in.

Comment: Considering that inbreeding was the core value of Slytherin I'd say that if it ever happen, Sly's half of the marriage was sorted there only by accident.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't find any absolute confirmations, making this an excellent (and annoying) question! However, here are some possibilities/notes on the subject.

**Known "family" houses**

It is [by no means guaranteed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/do-students-ever-get-sorted-into-houses-other-than-what-their-family-is-in) that family members are sorted into the same houses, but there are some patterns.

- James Potter, Lily Potter (née Evans), Harry Potter and James Potter Jr were all sorted into Gryffindor.
- Arthur Weasley and Molly Weasley (née Prewett), along with all their children, were Gryffindors.
- Lucius Malfoy, Narcissa Malfoy (née Black) and Draco Malfoy were all Slytherins.
- The Black family, bar Sirius, were all in Slytherin - as Slughorn said, "The whole Black family had been in my house, but Sirius ended up in Gryffindor! Shame — he was a talented boy. I got his brother Regulus when he came along, but I'd have liked the set."

**The Black family tapestry**

Based on this, I'm making an educated guess that members of the Black family tended to appear in Slytherin (and seemed to somehow disappear from the tapestry when they didn't), and that the Potters and the Weasleys tended to be Gryffindors. We know that members of the Longbottom and the Prewett family ended up in Gryffindor, but we don't have enough information to prove a family tradition.

A few traditionally "Gryffindor" names pop up on the Black family tapestry seen in the films. Although this isn't as canon as the books, we know JKR had a lot to do with the films, so it depends how much faith you put in that.

- Dorea Black (1920-1977) married Charlus Potter.
- Cedrella Black (unknown, likely 20th century based on tapestry placement) married Septimus Weasley (as pointed out by [GreenMatt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/36769/greenmatt) in the comments). Her spot is charred off the tapestry.

Also:

- Lucretia Black (1925-1992) married Ignatius Prewett.
- Callidora Black (1915-1996) married Harfang Longbottom.
- Arciorus (sp?) Black (1901-1991) married Melania Macmillan (possibly a relation of Ernie Macmillan, Hufflepuff).

**Trivia**

- Slytherins aren't always Death Eaters, or "Evil 4 Lyfe" - Regulus Black was a Slytherin and actively fought against Voldemort, albeit briefly; Slughorn was a Slytherin (and it's not difficult to picture him getting along with members other houses).
- Non-Slytherins [aren't always great either](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/were-there-or-are-there-any-dark-wizards-who-were-sorted-into-the-hufflepuff-h), producing their fair share of Dark Wizards.
- There's a pretty big canon precedent for romantic feelings between Gryffindor and Slytherin - Lily and Severus did maintain a friendship for several years (more than can be said for any Gryffindors/Slytherins we know of during Harry's time), and Snape's feelings are pretty well-known by the final book. I'd be surprised if Snape was the only Slytherin to ever fall in love with a Gryffindor (or vice versa).
- Hogwarts was founded over a thousand years ago, and [according to JKR](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood), "Slytherin's discrimination on the basis of parentage was considered an unusual and misguided view by the majority of wizards at the time. Contemporary literature suggests that Muggle-borns were not only accepted, but often considered to be particularly gifted." Opinion changed in the 17th Century after Muggle persecution, but we might think that before then, many Slytherins may not have had the vitriolic view of Muggle-borns that would might put many Gryffindors off considering them as a potential partner.
- By no means a direct link, but an interesting Pottermore marriage tidbit I only discovered the other day: Celestina Warbeck [was a Gryffindor](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/celestina-warbeck) and married three times (her backing dancer, her manager, and a composer). One of them may have been a Slytherin.

**Based on that, I conjecture that it is very likely that a Slytherin and a Gryffindor married at some point.**

A section of the tapestry, for reference:
[image: Black Family Tree Tapestry]

Comment: Very nice answer. Lily and Severus were in my mind too as I posted the question, hence why I specified *marriage* :-)

Comment: Oh great. @Slytherincess got a co-conspirator to whitewhash the House of Salazar :) Great answer though.

Comment: @DVK Nah, Ravenclaw over here with no particularly strong urges to clear the name of Slytherin - just saying, it's *possible* :)

Answer (score 8):

**TL:DR There are no confirmed instances, but given the scarcity of pure-blood families it is likely that at least one marriage between a Slytherin and a Gryffindor took place merely through lack of options**

> Magical opinion underwent something of a shift after the International Statute of Secrecy became effective in 1692, when the magical community went into voluntary hiding following persecution by Muggles. This was a traumatic time for witches and wizards, and marriages with Muggles dropped to their lowest level ever known, mainly because of fears that intermarriage would lead inevitably to discovery, and, consequently, to a serious infraction of wizarding law. 
>  [*Pottermore - Pure-Blood*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood)

The entire premise for my answer comes from this quote above and the fact that typically but not always Families have a traditional Hogwarts House. The fact that the majority of wizarding families had to breed among themselves leads me to believe that there was a greater chance of a Slytherin to Marry a Gryffindor. With a limited number of families to choose from anyway, and then ideally finding someone you are somewhat interested in reduces numbers significantly.

It's almost important to note that whilst Slytherins (at least the ones we know of) tend to be of a more pure-blood wizard only marriages, we know that Andromeda Tonks married a muggle, as did Isla Black. This seems more uncharacteristic for a Slytherin than Marrying a pure-blood Gryffindor (which as far as we know could be a School only rivalry).

I have found no absolute confirmed instances of a Slytherin and a Gryffindor marrying. I have split my answer into three sections.

1. Possibilities Taken from Canon
2. Canon Black Family Tree Marriages (The one JK Drew and Auctioned)
3. Non-Canon (film) Black Family Tree Marriages

*Although it could be stated that the film tree is also canon as JKR drew it, I believe if she was 100% happy with it she would have included it in her charity auction drawing*

### Possibilities Taken From Canon

**Fleamont Potter (James's Dad) and Euphemia (Last Name Unknown)**

All we really know about Euphemia is that she must have been a pure-blood as James was a pure-blood which leaves us with very little to go on.

**Minerva McGonagall and Elphinstone Urquart**

Given that:

> Through all her early years at Hogwarts, Minerva McGonagall remained on terms of friendship with her old boss at the Ministry, Elphinstone Urquart.

and that:

> and fond of her **much older** boss, Elphinstone Urquart
>   *Both Excerpts can be found on [Pottermore - Professor McGonagall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall).*

Minerva and Elphinstone met at the MoM, it is unlikely that Minerva would have held any Hogwarts House prejudice towards Elphy, now we know that Minerva is a Gryffindor but I couldn't find anything about Elphy's House unfortunately.

### Canon Black Family Tree

Taken from [here](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/blackfamilytree.html).

A lot of my reasons for suggesting the following were pairings of Gryffindor and Slytherin falls down to our current knowledge of the family names and their Hogwarts House.

**Callidora Black and Harfang Longbottom**

Presumably this would be Nevilles Great Grandfather and Great Grandmother. We know Neville is a Gryffindor and that his father was also brave enough to fight Voldemort and never give up any secrets even under Cruciatus (leading me to believe he was also a Gryffindor). Whether or not the rest of his ancestors were Gryffindor is speculation but It seems likely enough to me.

**Lucretia Black and Ignatius Prewett**

This would presumably be Molly's Father, given the time stated on the black family tree. Again it is possible from the family name that he was a Gryffindor.

**Cedrella Black and Septimus Weasley**

This would be Arthur's parents, which again leads us to the same speculation of a Slytherin (Black) and Gryffindor (Weasley) paring. I think it is stronger here considering that out of all the Weasleys we know they are all in Gryffindor.

### Non-Canon Black Family Tree (Film)

**Charlus Potter and Dorea Black**

Again another Potter marrying into the Black family, which is another possible G -> S marriage.

### **Marriages that have no leading evidence towards a Slytherin and Gryffindor union but has a tiny slither of hope.**

**Sirius Black and Hesper Gamp**

Whilst we have no knowledge of the Gamp family other than one of them created the laws of transfiguration, I thought it was a possible pairing (perhaps more likely a Ravenclaw)

**Belvina Black and Herbert Burke**

Who are most likely the Parents of Mr.Burke from Borgins and Burkes. Probably Slytherins with their Dark Arts and Items! *shakes fist*

**Charis Black and Caspar Crouch**

Barty Crouch Seniors Parents, I don't believe it's known what house Barty Crouch was in. I presume Junior was a Slytherin considering his Death Eater ties.

**Cygnus Black and Druella Rosier**

Evan Rosier (Modern Day Rosier) was a confirmed Death Eater.

1) **Licorus Black and Magenta Tripe**
2) **Jimbo Blishwick and Misapinoa Black**
3) **Cygnus Black I and Ella Max**

Comment: OK, finished reading. +1, but I think some bits should be removed as they're most likely Slytherin-Slytherin matches (e.g. Black-Burke) or there's no evidence for any Gryffindority (e.g. Black-Gamp, Black-Crouch).

Comment: Neville's grandmother's name is Augusta Longbottom. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help @Luna Loved your bit about Celestina btw!

Answer (score 4):

We know Andromeda Black and Ted Tonks were  probably in different houses because Slytherin rarely allows Muggleborns. Andromeda was in Slytherin

> She attended Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry in the 1960s and was sorted into Slytherin House.

Ted Tonks' house is unknown, but I think it was either Gryffindor or Hufflepuff, because he is *very* brave and his daughter was a Hufflepuff.

Comment: Hum... There probably were Slytherin Muggleborns - see [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46679/98028). Also, the Ted Tonks part is quite speculative, I might say. Also, you might want to add more info that the existing answers :)