# Are there any instances of members of different Hogwarts houses coupling up and marrying each other?

Tags: harry-potter

Being a casual fan of the books, it occurred to me that in most cases, the couples I have seen in the *Harry Potter* stories all seem to come from the same house, with Harry and Cho Chang being an exception. This makes a certain amount of sense; the [mostly] friendly rivalry of Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, and Slytherin would to an extent preclude extended fraternization, and most time spent outside of study would be with housemates, both same sex and opposite. So it makes a bit of sense that most probable couple bounds or opportunities to pair up may occur literally "in-house". This would be elevated by the fact that, due to house members sharing similar traits and possible alignments, they would naturally have more in common with housemates [values, views, personality quirks, shared interests] which would be the best elements to build upon.

Close friendships aren't precluded by houses, though; Cedric Diggory was purportedly liked by most people, regardless of House affiliation, for instance. In *The Cursed Child,* concurrently, Albus and his cousin are in different houses, and grow steadily distant while he grows close to a *Malfoy.* So its not at all impossible that close friends can come from different houses, let alone crushes or possible paramours.

I was just wondering if I missed something, and if there were any in-canon examples of couples who came from different houses yet had successful relationships?

Comment: I originally answered with Cho Chang and Cedric Diggory as one could argue it counts as a _"successful relationship"_, however, your title mentions marriage. Do you specifically want to know only couples who have married from different houses or does any inter House relationship count?

Comment: Related: [Did any Gryffindor marry a Slytherin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108042/31394)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I asked about marriage specifically because I reasoned that would be an indicator of a "successful" relationship which continued beyond school years, but I'm open to examples of any couple bound which shows mutual respect and deep care, even without marriage. Successful teenage relationships would also be acceptable.

Comment: @RussRainford Okay, as Skooba has provided a good example in the meantime I'll leave my answer deleted though!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot One answer is a good start, but I was hoping for more, so please don't be made to feel as though any other examples you can provide will not be equally valued.

Comment: @RussRainford Oh I don't, I just feel like mine doesn't quite match the intent as well and we don't really want this turning into a list with one example per answer.

Comment: reminds me of the plot of "Blood Red Rivers" (Book), "The Crimson Rivers" (Movie) ...

Comment: Bill and Fleur are at least an example of a Gryffindor marrying a non-Gryffindor (although Fleur might have been in Gryffindor had she gone to Hogwarts). Also, Luna marries the grandson of Newt Scamander, so if Hufflepuff runs in the family, that could be a Ravenclaw/Hufflepuff one.

Comment: I'm glad there are examples - otherwise it almost seems to be that these kids are matched for life from age 11!  That seems more like contractual marriage arrangements (linking estates, etc.) than love-matches that the books mostly seem to focus on.

Comment: I was going to suggest Jacob and Tina (I think I got the names right?) from the Fantastic Beasts series, but then I remembered neither of them is from a *Hogwarts* house, her being from one of the American houses and him being a mugg- err, nomag.  Also jury's still out on how successful that relationship will be.

Comment: Do the two have to have been at Hogwarts at the same time? If not, Remus Lupin (Gryffindor) and Nymphador Tonks (Hufflepuff) would count here.

Comment: @Luna She (Fleur) might have been a Gryffindor, but it might be worth noting the Beauxbatons students gravitate towards the Ravenclaw table. I'm sure it can't be that all of the Beauxbatons students (or even just the select group brought along to enter the Tournament) would have been best suited to Ravenclaw, but it adds a little more to a nice thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another example. If we consider the "Harry Potter: Wizards Unite" game canon, then there's a mention of a happy marriage between [Grim Fawley](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Grim_Fawley) (Hufflepuff) and [Penelope Padgett](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Penelope_Fawley) (Slytherin).

Answer (score 43):

**[Neville Longbottom](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/neville-longbottom), a Gryffindor, married [Hannah Abbott](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/hannah-abbott), a Hufflepuff.**

> [Questioner] Did Neville ever find love?
>
> [JKR] Of course. … To make him extra cool he marries the woman who becomes, eventually, the new landlady at The Leaky Cauldron, which I think would make him very cool among the students, that he lives above the pub. He marries Hannah Abbott.
>
> <sub>[*J.K. Rowling at Carnegie Hall*, October 20, 2007.](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more)</sub>

**[Remus Lupin](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/remus-lupin), a Gryffindor, married [Nymphadora Tonks](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/nymphadora-tonks), a Hufflepuff.**

Seems like Gryffindor men have a affinity for Hufflepuff women...

Comment: Wasn't he going to confess to Luna at the end of the last movie? I guess that didn't pan out.

Comment: @Parrotmaster, movies and books are quite different

Answer (score 0):

Tonks parents were from differents houses and had a succesfull marriage too. Her mom Andromeda was a Slytherin and her dad Ted Tonks was never specified but he was a muggleborn so it's unlikkely that he was a Slytherin.

Comment: We have no canon support for _either_ of their houses which is why I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: I though Andromeda house was clearly Slytherin and can be supported by a comment Slughorn made to Harry in chapter 4, book 6 and I quote: "The whole Black family had been in my house, but Sirius ended up in Gryffindor!". Is cannon that Slughorn was a teacher since before Voldemort until his retirement when he was replaced by Snape so is cannon too that he teached Bellatrix, Andromeda, Narcissa, Sirius and Regulus. His word should be enough to make it cannon what house Andromeda was. I know we don't have a proof of Ted house but his status as muggleborn made me infer that he's not a Slytherin.