# Is "Harry Potter: Wizards Unite" canon?

Tags: harry-potter, canon

After reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218793/75000), I started wondering if HP:WU actually is canon. I did some research and found two contradictory stories.

From [Wizards Unite Hub](https://wizardsunitehub.info/wiki/the-calamity):

> "The events in Wizards Unite are happening after the events of main Harry Potter books and they **are considered to be canon**."

But then from [Tech Radar](https://www.techradar.com/news/harry-potter-wizards-unite):

> "JK Rowling isn’t involved with Wizards Unite’s story, so **how canon the plot is is arguable**."

I'm not sure how credible either of these sources are, so I thought I'd ask here.

**Is Harry Potter: Wizards Unite a part of the HP extended-canon? If yes, how much of it is considered so?**

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate since it seems to just be a specific example of the general question. See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/136123/100430

Comment: Fair enough. I'll make a comment there.

Comment: By the way, if you’re specifically looking for updated answers in light of new information, there is a bounty reason for that.

Comment: That costs money though. It's cheaper to ask a new question.