# Are there any good Slytherins besides Snape and Slughorn?

Tags: harry-potter, slytherin

Presumably Slytherins aren't inherently bad, they just value different traits in a person compared to the other houses. But it seems that in the stories, being a Slytherin equates more or less with being a death eater, or at least a Voldemort sympathizer.

The only exceptions I can think of are Snape and Slughorn, and even Snape was a death eater for while before switching sides.

Are there any other good Slytherins?

Comment: Albus Potter probably.

Comment: And Scorpius Malfoy

Comment: Draco Malfoy and his mother, Narcissa. Plus, the great Merlin.

Comment: I would argue that neither Snape nor Slughorn are good.  Yes, they were working against Voldemort, but that in itself doesn't make them good.  Being good is about your character, your values, and your morality... not which side you fight for.

Snape and Slughorn are both very flawed, morally reprehensible people.

Snape is a creepy stalker pining for the woman who friend-zoned him.  He's a sadist and a bully. 

Slughorn is an unethical, narcissistic, greedy dabbler in the dark arts. He's too cowardly to do more than petty, selfish evils himself.

Neither of them is a good person.

Comment: Let's not forget the Slytherin reinforcements during the Battle of Hogwarts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Merlin

From the Pottermore house entrance letter for Slytherin

> *"Here’s a little-known fact that the other three houses don’t bring up much: Merlin was a Slytherin. Yes, Merlin himself, the most famous wizard in history! He learned all he knew in this very house! Do you want to follow in the footsteps of Merlin?"*

Also, arguably, Narcissa Malfoy, whose love for her own son saved Harry Potter.

Related: [Is Slytherin Evil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7403/is-slytherin-evil?rq=1)

Comment: So Merlin studied in Slytherin house 500 or 600 years AFTER he was active in 5th and 6th century Britain?  So Merlin mus thave lived for centuries, or else aged backwards as in The Once and Future King.

Comment: @M.A.Golding [We all know J.K. Rowling isn't great at math :)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143313/why-is-jk-rowling-considered-bad-at-math)